# Can I use GPMC to edit a local policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I might be overlooking something obvious here, but can I use the Group Policy Management Console on Windows Server to edit a local policy? When I launch it I get a message saying that the machine needs to be part of a domain to be able to edit the domain policy, but I was wondering if I could use it anyway for local settings.

Comment: Run - gpedit.msc

Comment: @TheCleaner But that's the Local Group Policy Editor, not the GPMC..

Comment: Right - as Chris and Per pointed out...it can't be done.  Sorry, I figured you simply wanted to know how to edit it and thought GPMC was the tool to use.

Comment: @TheCleaner No worries, the questions probably wasn't superclear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

<sub>Answers must be longer than xx characters.....</sub>

Comment: I couldn't have said it in fewer words.

Comment: It used to be a single editor for any Policy files back in the NT days, but since Windows 2000 it's been separate utilities.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

You can however launch gpedit.msc to start the Local Group Policy Editor and edit you Local Policy.

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked.